# How do I handle the MouseDown event from a TextBlock in code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, events

I have a `ListBox` with `TextBlocks` as list:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
 <TextBlock Name="Address1" MouseDown="SongAddress"/>
 <TextBlock Name="Address2" MouseDown="SongAddress"/>
 <TextBlock Name="Address3" MouseDown="SongAddress"/>
 <TextBlock Name="Address4" MouseDown="SongAddress"/> 
</ListBox>
```

There are four `TextBlocks` and each one of them have the MouseDown event. I want different action for each one of them, How could I handle from `code-behind` which one of them gets clicked?

Answer (score 0):

There are a numer of questions on StackOverflow which address this question. I am assuming you are familiar with [how to write the code for an event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF.

The signature would look something like:

```
private void SongAddress(object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
```

It is then -- in the case you mention -- up to you *how* you deal with the event. You could either implement a separate event handler for each button or you could cast `sender` to type `TextBlock` and grab distinguishing properties from there.

**Unsolicited Opinion**

Including similar `Name` property values and the same `MouseDown` event handler value alludes to the fact that each `TextBlock` share some conceptually similar purpose. You may want to figure out whether you actually need four separate handles or whether you can handle what you are trying to accomplish by better modeling your domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Preview
And name the TextBox

```
    <TextBox x:Name="tb01" PreviewMouseDown="tb01_PreviewMouseDown"/>

    private void tb01_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            string s = tb.Name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using different methods?

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
 <TextBlock Name="Address1" MouseDown="SongAddress1"/>
 <TextBlock Name="Address2" MouseDown="SongAddress2"/>
 <TextBlock Name="Address3" MouseDown="SongAddress3"/>
 <TextBlock Name="Address4"  MouseDown="SongAddress4"/> </ListBox>
```

Or maybe a Switch Case?

```
private void SongAddress(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    switch (((TextBlock) sender).Name)
    {
        case "Address1":
            //dosomething
            break;
        case "Address2":
            //dosomething
            break;
        case "Address3":
            //dosomething
            break;
        case "Address4":
            //dosomething
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paparazzi Its one of the ways to solve your problem. The other way I've shown is casting sender in your code behind to a Textblock and using it in a switch case.

Comment: I also appreciate this solution, thanks for helping me.